# Range Slider in Angular 10 is not working for decimal values

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, angular10, angular11

I am working on a range slider but I observed setting values in decimal is not working fine in Angular 10+.
It is strange that if I did the same code in just HTML alone it is working fine.

app.component.html:

```
<input
  #slider3
  type="range"
  min="1.3"
  max="2.7"
  value="1.9"
  step="0.1"
/>
Result: {{ output}}
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('slider3', { read: ElementRef })
  public sliderOne: ElementRef;
  output;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('..', this.sliderOne.nativeElement.value);
    this.output = this.sliderOne.nativeElement.value;
  }
}
```

The output should be 1.9.

I could see in HTML only the same result as well as till Angular 9 version but from Angular 10 I am seeing a different output 2.3

We can remove the value property and directly set the this.sliderOne.nativeElement.value = '1.9' or using ngmodel as answered by @rahultiwari will work fine.

But I am wondering why it is working till in Angular 9 but not after that?

Angular 9:(correct output)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-vxny4j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Angular 11:(wrong output)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-new-r2l1ta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

```
<input #input type="range" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" [step]="params.step" 
[min]="params.min" [max]="params.max">

<div>
 <pre><code>{{input.value}}</code></pre>
</div>



import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
 })
export class AppComponent {
name = 'Angular';

params = { 
defaultValue: 70.5,
min: 30,
max: 120,
step: 0.1 
};

inputValue: number = this.params.defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Ngmodel is working but my question is why it is not working with value property which was working fine till angular 9. If you remove the value property and  directly set the value like this.sliderOne.nativeElement.value = 70.5 will work fine;

Answer (score 0):

I change some thing, becaouse there are some problem with angular Lifecycle that create the error.

```html
 <input
  #slider3
  type="range"
  min="1.3"
  max="2.7"
  step="0.1"
  (change)="setVal($event)"
/>
Result: {{ output}}
```

component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('slider3', { read: ElementRef }) public sliderOne: ElementRef;
  public output = 1.9;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('..', this.sliderOne.nativeElement.value);
    this.sliderOne.nativeElement.value = this.output;
  }

  setVal(e) {
    this.output = e.target.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is one of the workaround. If you observe you have to remove the value attribute. I already had a workaround for it but my question is why it is not working in angular 10+.